# Error Using Jenkins to execute oracle script at remote database?

Tags: jenkins, oracle11g, jenkins-plugins, devops

I am using sqlplus-script-runner plugin to run my sql command at remote server as my screenshot, but I got error:

**ERROR: ORACLE_HOME directory [10.53.253.161:1521/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1] does not exist!**

Do you know how to config Oracle_home of remote db ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer: Oracle_home is oracle path on my local machine and[image] include the remote ip on the instance

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your url to 10.53.253.161:1521/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0

Does Jenkins user have visibility to that folder?

Comment: I still get error. I can access db using pls sql developer with tnsname as below  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.53.253.161)(PORT = 1521)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA =       
      (SERVICE_NAME = test12cp1) 
    ) 
  )

Comment: I can access ftp to that path, too

Comment: Is ORACLE_HOME variable setted on remote computer?

Comment: yes, at server 10.53.253.161, ORACLE_HOME is set to /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

Comment: I tried to change instance to " (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.53.253.161)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = test12cp1) ) )", but still got the same error